# exportar de pandas groupby apply np.array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tengo un fichero .csv con 16 mil filas y 15 columnas... de este fichero cojo sólo la Licencia que no es más que un identificador de producto y la fecha asociada a cada una de ellas.

LICENCIA      FECHA
FE-101        01/09/19 00:10
FE-145        03/09/19 04:11
FE-162        04/09/19 05:46
FE-139        05/09/19 08:56
FE-156        07/09/19 09:10
FE-162        10/09/19 20:45
FE-159        12/09/19 21:23
FE-162        25/09/19 22:23

después de aplicar mi salida en consola es algo así... que es justo lo que yo quiero... primera columna toda la lista de identificadores ordenados
como etiqueta o encabezado de fila (ahora aparece sólo una vez y las filas se reducen a 64) y a continuación en una única fila las 16 mil fechas asociadas a cada uno de ellos en 
unos hai 100 fechas y en otros 500 fechas.

```
FE-101       [01/09/19 15:35, 01/09/19 16:45, 01/09/19 16:5...  
FE-102       [01/09/19 05:44, 01/09/19 06:07, 01/09/19 06:1...  
FE-103       [02/09/19 08:05, 02/09/19 08:16, 02/09/19 08:4..  
.  
.  
.  
FE-188       [01/09/19 15:35, 01/09/19 16:45, 01/09/19 16:5...  
FE-189       [01/09/19 05:44, 01/09/19 06:07, 01/09/19 06:1...  
FE-190       [02/09/19 08:05, 02/09/19 08:16, 02/09/19 08:4...  
Name: FECHA, dtype: object>
```

Lo que no consigo es que al exportarlo a .csv o txt se mantenga ese formato. Cuando abro el fichero exportado se muesta

FE-101 fecha 1  fecha 2 fecha 3 fecha 4
fecha 5 fecha 6 fecha 7 fecha 8

y así hasta completar las fechas de ese identificador

a continuación sigue con el resto de identificadores siempre así identificador cuatro fechas y salto de carro y otras cuatro...

yo quiero identificador todas sus fechas y asi todas las filas. He probado varias cosas pero no me sale y no sé exactamente que buscar para conseguirlo

```
    datos = pd.read_csv('s201909.csv',usecols=['LICENCIA', 'FECHA'], encoding = 'utf-8')

    # otras operaciones y me quedo con un DataFrame llamado : nuevo

    datfra = pd.DataFrame(nuevo)

    # aplico groupby y apply y ningún error

    datfra = datfra.groupby('LICENCIA')['FECHA'].apply(np.array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se debe a que Pandas cuando se encuentra con una columna de tipo `object` como es un `numpy.array`, a la hora de pasar dicho objeto al csv llama a su método `__str__` (el que usa `print` también). NumPy por defecto trunca los arrays al imprimirlos si tienen muchos items y limita el número máximo de caracteres por linea a 75 (como marcan las convenciones de estilo de Python) para facilitar la legibilidad y esto es lo que termina en tu csv:

> ```
> >>> import numpy as np
> >>> arr = np.arange(100)
> >>> print(arr)
>
> [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
>  24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
>  48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71
>  72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95
>  96 97 98 99]
> ```

La solución es modificar temporalmente cómo NumPy imprime sus arrays:

```
import sys

with np.printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize, linewidth=sys.maxsize):
    datfra.to_csv("salida.csv")
```

Que generará un csv tal que:

> ```
> FE-101,['01/09/19 00:10' '02/09/19 00:10' '03/09/19 00:10' '04/09/19 00:10' '05/09/19 00:10']
> FE-145,['06/09/19 04:11' '07/09/19 04:11' '08/09/19 04:11' '09/09/19 04:11' '10/09/19 04:11' '11/09/19 04:11']
> ```

O puedes usar `list` en vez de `numpy.array`:

```
datfra = datfra.groupby('LICENCIA')['FECHA'].apply(list)
datfra.to_csv(csv_file)
```

> ```
> FE-101,"['01/09/19 00:10', '02/09/19 00:10', '03/09/19 00:10', '04/09/19 00:10', '05/09/19 00:10']"
> FE-145,"['06/09/19 04:11', '07/09/19 04:11', '08/09/19 04:11', '09/09/19 04:11', '10/09/19 04:11', '11/09/19 04:11']"
> ```